# How to send terminal output to text file without newline

Tags: command-line

I am using the find command to find files of a certain type recursevely in subdirectories. I am trying to send the output from the 'find' command to a text file. However the long file paths returned get split onto multiple lines. I would like to output each file path on a single line.

The command I am using is something like

find /path/to/directories -name *.cdf > filelist.txt

the output I get looks like:

```
/path/to/directories/directory1/subdir
ectory1/file1.cdf
/path/to/directories/directory1/subdir
ectory1/file2.cdf
/path/to/directories/directory2/subdir
ectory2/file3.cdf
```

I want my output file to look like:

```
/path/to/directories/directory1/subdirectory1/file1.cdf
/path/to/directories/directory1/subdirectory2/file2.cdf
/path/to/directories/directory2/subdirectory1/file3.cdf
```

Any help on how to accomplish this would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It is already as you want. It looks like terminal or whatever software you use to view it wraps lines. Just do in terminal `cat filelist.txt`.

Comment: `less -S filelist.txt` will also show the lines unfolded

Comment: Typically, terminals hold 80 characters, and as described above, will 'soft-wrap' text over 80 characters.  This changes as you resize your terminal.

Comment: Yes, you were quite right and it was the software (emacs) wraping the lines. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Your Terminal window is too narrow for the lines to be displayed on a single line (per filename).

- Hold the left <kbd>ALT</kbd>-key,
- while doing so; place mouse pointer over either window side, inside the window,
- hold down the MIDDLE mouse button
- and drag to resize the window.

Let go of the mouse button and then <kbd>ALT</kbd> as you're content.